# Is there an online database for seeing patent applications from India?

Tags: databases, application, india, websites

Is there a website similar to [EPO](http://www.epo.org/searching/free/espacenet.html) or [USPTO](http://www.uspto.gov/) to see Indian Patent applications (Not filed patents)?

Comment: This site is about US patents and related law, your question may be off topic in this forum.

Comment: For purposes of locating prior art one could/should search widely. This is not a question on Indian patent law but a question about locating information. Published documents on a worldwide basis ca be used to invalidate U.S. patents.

Comment: @RonJ. This site was launched to take advantage of recent changes to the US Patent system. Having said that, **non-US questions about patents are welcome here,** and our hope is that over time, the site will become the place to find prior art and get good answers to hard questions on patents everywhere. See [Is this site only and specifically for the USA patent system?](http://meta.patents.stackexchange.com/a/22/1).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use http://ipindiaservices.gov.in/patentsearch/search/index.aspx to search all patents in India including granted and published patent applications in India.